# Writing to a HttpResponse with BufferOutput=false blocks when an ActionResult comes from a ASP.NET MVC 4 asynchronous action and Glimpse is enabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await, glimpse

I have a custom ActionResult that sets HttpResponse.BufferOutput = false and then writes data to the response stream. I noticed that when the action result comes from a task-based asynchronous action method in ASP.NET MVC, writing to the response stream blocks. This happens *only* when Glimpse plugin is enabled in web.config. Glimpse is very useful to me, I really want to have it enabled, at least during development and testing. BufferOutput property should remain false, because the content length can be quite large and I don't want to buffer it in memory.

This is the shortest code that could reproduce this exact behaviour:

```
public sealed class CustomResult : ActionResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var resp = context.HttpContext.Response;
        resp.BufferOutput = false;
        resp.ContentType = "text/plain";
        resp.Output.Write(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());
        resp.Flush();
    }
}

public sealed class DownloadController : Controller
{
    // the client nevers gets the response from this action
    public async Task<ActionResult> Async()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        return new CustomResult();
    }

    // this works
    public ActionResult Sync()
    {
        return new CustomResult();
    }
}
```

I tested this with the latest Glimpse.Mvc4 package (version 1.3.2).

Am I doing something wrong, is there a workaround to this issue or is this a Glimpse bug and I should report it?

Comment: This looks idd like a bug. Would you mind reporting this on the [Glimpse Issue Tracker](https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse/issues)?

Comment: @cgijbels Sure - https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/502